# How to update an object with ManyToMany relation with doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

Hi there Stack Overflow members!
I have doctrine 2 installed everything work perfectly,
I have generated my entities and proxies with command ,

my problem is when I try to update an entities with many to many relation ship
I had this problem

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '8-1' for key 'PRIMARY''

it seems that doctrine try to insert a new entities and not trying to update joined table
if there any problem in my code , is there any example clear ?
thanks

```
    //update entities user


     $user=$this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->find((int)$this->input->post('id'));

     $user->setNom($this->input->post('nom'));
     $user->setPrenom($this->input->post('prenom'));

    //update entities services(user have many service)

    foreach($this->input->post('services') as $post){
        $service = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Service')->find((int)$post);
              if ($service instanceof Entities\Service) {
                  $user->addService($service);
        }
    $this->em->flush();
```

Comment: there's missing closing curry bracket } for the foreach loop and please tell what is the Primary key of your table

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your example, you are not persisting any entities, therefore Doctrine doesn't register any changes, and flush has nothing to update.

You have to persist the owning side of the relationship.

```
$this->em->persist($service);
```

or

```
$this->em->persist($user);
```

Depends what did you specify as the owning side.

Check out  the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side)

Comment: The $service and $user were retrieved from the 'em' and they are being managed and you don't need to call persist()